# How to setup automatic issue transitions in Jira?

Tags: scripting, mercurial, jira, atlassian-fisheye

We are moving from another issue tracking platform to Jira. How could i set up scripts that do  issue state transitions automatically without having to log into Jira? Should i setup custom services?

Another case is when someone pushes code to mercurial. how could i setup automatic issue transitions on this event("development finished")?

I have Jira Atlassian,Fisheye, Mercurial up and running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the automatic issue transition, check out the script runner
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner

There are plenty of examples and built-in scripts allowing to implement this type of functionality (and much more)

For your second question, you can use the 'smart commit' feature provided by fisheye
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+Smart+Commits

It works ok with svn, not sure about hg.

Francis

Comment: Thank you, for the first part i decided to use ANT scripts in combination with JRJC (Jira REST Java Client) API. Ill definitely look into smart commits for the second part.